# Globbing error due to whitespace

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

My directory variable

```
POSTMAP="/work/Documents/Projects/untitled\ folder/untitled\ folder/*/*_tsta.bam"
```

My for statement:

```
for file0 in ${POSTMAP}; do
...
```

It seems that the whitespace in 'untitled folder' messes with the globbing. I suspect this because file0 ends up being '/untitled'. Note that I have 'shopt -s extglob'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really *messing up with the globbing*. Here, by using `$POSTMAP` unquoted, you're using the split+glob operator.

With the default value of `$IFS`, on your `/work/Documents/Projects/untitled\ folder/untitled\ folder/*/*_tsta.bam`, it will first split it into `"/work/Documents/Projects/untitled\"`, `"folder/untitled\"` and `"folder/*/*_tsta.bam"`. Only the third one contains wildcard characters and thus be subject to the glob part. However, the glob would just search for files in the `folder` directory relative to the current directory.

If you only want the `glob` part and not the `split` of that `split+glob` operator, set `$IFS` to the empty string. For that operator, backslash can't be used to escape `$IFS` separators (with `bash` (and `bash` only among Bourne-like shells), it can be used to escape wildcard glob operators though).

So either:

```
POSTMAP="/work/Documents/Projects/untitled folder/untitled folder/*/*_tsta.bam"
IFS=   # don't split
set +f # do glob
for file0 in $POSTMAP # invoke the split+glob operator
do...
```

Or probably better here with shells supporting arrays like `bash`, `yash`, `zsh`, `ksh`:

```
postmap=(
  '/work/Documents/Projects/untitled folder/untitled folder/'*/*_tsta.bam
) # expand the glob at the time of that array assignment
for file0 in "${postmap[@]}" # loop over the array elements
do....
```

Comment: Thank you. For the second suggestion can you place the closing apostrophe after .bam like ('/work/Documents/Projects/untitled folder/untitled folder/*/*_tsta.bam')? Also what is the advantage of using the 2nd rather than 1st suggestion for the purpose of building a for loop?

Comment: @mattqdean. No. Obviously, globs are not expanded within quotes. You can quote whatever you like _except_ those wildcard characters with whatever type of quoting you like. Like `postmap=('/work/Do'"cume"\n\t\s\/$'Project'$"s/untitled fo"'lder/untitled folder/'*"/"*'_tsta.bam')`, here alternating (for no good reason except demonstration) the different types of shell quotes (`'...'`, backslash, `"..."`, `$'...'`, `$"..."`).